# Core Data: Setting an NSSet Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

So I have the following entities:

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var name: String
  @NSManaged var dogs: NSSet 
}  

class Dog: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var name: String
  @NSManaged var owner: NSManagedObject
}
```

And I think I must have tried like five different ways to set the dogs NSSet and the owner NSManagedObject, all with no luck.

```
self.mutableSetValueForKey("dogs").addObject(newDog)
```

is crashing and throwing "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'"

I tried both of these options:

```
var newDogs = [newDog]
var setOfDogs = NSSet(array: newDogs) as Set<NSObject>    
self.dogs.setByAddingObjectsFromSet(setOfDogs)
self.dogs.setByAddingObjectsFromArray(newDogs)
```

neither of which threw and exception, but self.dogs is empty after using either/both of those.

Also, when setting dog.owner, how do I do that?  I know there are methods that are dog.owner.setValue(Value, Key), but I'm not really sure what the value and key refer to and the documentation hasn't been super helpful.

I know there are some similar questions on here like this, but they all seem to be in Obj-C and I'm having trouble following them.  Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you subclass `NSManagedObject`, you should be using the subclasses:

```
@NSManaged var owner : Person
```

Second, you do not have to care about the complexity of setting the `NSSet` in one-to-many relationships. Instead, simply set to to-one relationship.

```
dog.owner = person
```

That's it.

Finally, for future reference, here is how you set/modify the `NSSet`. This is necessary when you have a many-to-many relationship.

```
let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("dogs")
items.addObject(newDog)
```

You can simplify this by adding convenience methods to your `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Comment: why not "mutableCopy"? just to avoid possible compilation errors

Comment: You don't want a copy. You should not be trying to trick the compiler but let it help you write solid, efficient and economical code.

Comment: This Crashes My App: [_SwiftValue entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @BrandonA Try moving to Swift where this type of error is unlikely to occur.